# Flutter WebView font size is bigger than it should be

Tags: css, ios, flutter, webview

I'm currently rendering this website using `flutter_inappwebview` and everything works fine but I noticed some texts have bigger size than normal. This is happening throughout the app. We use `rem` units to define `font-size` in the css. Could this be related?

I found android webview settings have `minimumFontSize` but this problem is happening on iOS.

How it looks on Web
[image: Original Image]

How it looks using Flutter Webview (ios simulator)
[image: Simulator Image]

I already tried something like

```dart
   crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
      minimumFontSize: 1,
    ),
```

But I think this is a setting that only really affects android devices.

Comment: Does looking to see exactly what CSS has been generated throw any light on the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a flutter/webview question. In fact in the safari app for iOS, you should see similar larger fonts than normal. To solve this, you can refer to other issues mentioned around this issue:
[Why is font-size different on iOS Chrome v. iOS Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62668640/why-is-font-size-different-on-ios-chrome-v-ios-safari)